# Subgroup relations in $GL(3,\mathbb Z)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

There are 73 conjugacy classes of finite subgroups in $\operatorname{GL}(3,\mathbb{Z})$. If you take 73 representatives, you will find group-subgroup relations between them. There must exist an overview from the maximal subgroups (I believe there are 14?) to the trivial group, but I don't seem to be able to find it.

Comment: According to Morris Newman, in his book "Integral matrices",page 181, there are 70, not 73,  conjugacy classes of finite subgroups in $\mathrm{GL}(3,\mathbb Z)$. Where did you get 73?

Comment: Newman is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a natural homomorphism from $\operatorname{GL}(3,\mathbb{Z})$ to $\operatorname{GL}(3,\mathbb{F}_3)$, by which each finite subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(3,\mathbb{Z})$ is mapped injectively to a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(3,\mathbb{F}_3)$. From subgroup lattice in later, one can obtain subgroup lattice in $\operatorname{GL}(3,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://tinyurl.com/6598g69)? This is for $GL(2,\mathbb{F}_3)$ so then I would expect 13 groups... I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: @Wox: GL(n,Z/mZ) has more (conjugacy classes of) finite subgroups than GL(n,Z), but if you only look at the subgroups of GL(n,Z/mZ) that lift to subgroups of GL(n,Z) then you should get something closer to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Tahara (1971) (citation below) gives representatives for the 73 $\mathbb{Z}$-conjugacy classes of finite subgroups in $\mathrm{GL}(3,\mathbb{Z})$.

Below is Magma code that

1. defines these representative subgroups;
2. verifies pairwise $\mathbb{Z}$-nonconjugacy; and
3. for each subgroup, prints the set of its maximal subgroups up to $\mathbb{Z}$-conjugacy.

The desired subgroup lattice can be constructed from this maximal-subgroup information. The code takes about 2 seconds to run on [Magma's online calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/).

**Remark 1.** The Magma code below saves all 73 representative subgroups in a sequence (i.e. list). For each of the 73 representative subgroups, the code computes its maximal subgroups; for each maximal subgroup, the code identifies the index of the unique representative subgroup (in the sequence of 73) to which it is $\mathbb{Z}$-conjugate. The sets output by item 3 above are sets of these indices.

**Remark 2.** The Magma code below identifies 4 maximal finite subgroups (up to $\mathbb{Z}$-conjugacy) of $\mathrm{GL}(3,\mathbb{Z})$, named S64, S71, S72, and S73 in the code. For convenience, these subgroups are
$$
S_{64} = \left\langle{}A_{6},B_{2},-I\right\rangle{}
\qquad
S_{71} = \left\langle{}C_{4},D_{2},-I\right\rangle{}
\\
S_{72} = \left\langle{}D_{4},K_{2},-I\right\rangle{}
\qquad
S_{73} = \left\langle{}E_{4},J_{2},-I\right\rangle{}
$$
where
$$
I = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\\
B_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
D_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\\
J_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
K_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}
\\
C_{4} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
D_{4} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\\
E_{4} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ -2 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
A_{6} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

**Remark 3.** Tahara (1971) lists 74 subgroups. Two are $\mathbb{Z}$-conjugate.

#### References

[Tah1971] Ken-ichi Tahara, *On the finite subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}(3,\mathbb{Z})$*, Nagoya Mathematical Journal, Volume 41 (1971), 169--209.

#### Magma code

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////80
//
//  Magma code.
//  (1) Defines the finite subgroups of GL(3,Z) listed in Tahara (1971), "On the
//      finite subgroups of GL(3,Z)", Nagoya Mathematical Journal, Vol. 41,
//      169--209.
//  (2) Verifies pairwise Z-nonconjugacy.
//  (3) For each subgroup, prints the set of its maximal subgroups up to
//      Z-conjugacy.
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



Z := IntegerRing();
G := GL(3,Z);



//  Define conjugacy-class representatives of finite subgroups of GL(3,Z).
//  Obtained from Tahara (1971).

//  Define the matrices in GL(3,Z) that serve as the building blocks.

//  Order 1.
I := G ! Matrix([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]);
//  Order 2.
A2 := G ! Matrix([[1,0,0],[0,-1,0],[0,0,-1]]); //  eq A6^3 eq A4^2 eq B4^2
B2 := G ! Matrix([[-1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]]);
C2 := G ! Matrix([[-1,0,0],[0,-1,0],[0,0,1]]);
D2 := G ! Matrix([[-1,0,0],[0,0,-1],[0,-1,0]]);
E2 := G ! Matrix([[-1,0,0],[1,0,-1],[-1,-1,0]]);
F2 := G ! Matrix([[-1,1,-1],[0,0,-1],[0,-1,0]]);
G2 := G ! Matrix([[0,0,-1],[0,-1,0],[-1,0,0]]);
H2 := G ! Matrix([[-1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,-1]]);
I2 := G ! Matrix([[0,-1,1],[0,-1,0],[1,-1,0]]);
J2 := G ! Matrix([[-1,-1,-1],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]]); //  eq D4^2
K2 := G ! Matrix([[-1,-1,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,-1]]);
//  Order 3.
A3 := G ! Matrix([[1,0,0],[0,0,-1],[0,1,-1]]);
B3 := G ! Matrix([[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,0,0]]);
//  Order 4.
A4 := G ! Matrix([[1,0,0],[0,0,-1],[0,1,0]]);
B4 := G ! Matrix([[1,0,1],[0,0,-1],[0,1,0]]);
C4 := G ! Matrix([[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[-1,0,0]]);
D4 := G ! Matrix([[0,-1,0],[1,1,1],[-1,0,0]]);
E4 := G ! Matrix([[1,1,0],[-2,-1,-1],[0,0,1]]);
//  Order 6.
A6 := G ! Matrix([[1,0,0],[0,0,-1],[0,1,1]]);

//  Define the subgroups.

//  Order 1 : 1 class.
S01 := sub<G | {I}>;
//  Order 2 : 5 classes.
S02 := sub<G | {A2}>; //  W1
S03 := sub<G | {-A2}>; //  W2
S04 := sub<G | {B2}>; //  W3
S05 := sub<G | {-B2}>; //  W4
S06 := sub<G | {-I}>; //  W5
//  Order 3 : 2 classes.
S07 := sub<G | {A3}>; //  W1
S08 := sub<G | {B3}>; //  W2
//  Order 4 : 4 + 11 = 15 classes.
//      Isomorphic to C_{4} : 4 classes.
S09 := sub<G | {A4}>; //  W1
S10 := sub<G | {-A4}>; //  W2
S11 := sub<G | {B4}>; //  W3
S12 := sub<G | {-B4}>; //  W4
//      Isomorphic to C_{2} x C_{2} : 11 classes.
S13 := sub<G | {A2,-I}>; //  W5
S14 := sub<G | {A2,C2}>; //  W6
S15 := sub<G | {A2,-C2}>; //  W7
S16 := sub<G | {A2,D2}>; //  W8
S17 := sub<G | {A2,-D2}>; //  W9
S18 := sub<G | {-A2,-D2}>; //  W10
S19 := sub<G | {B2,-I}>; //  W11
S20 := sub<G | {B2,E2}>; //  W12
S21 := sub<G | {B2,-E2}>; //  W13
S22 := sub<G | {B2,F2}>; //  W14
S23 := sub<G | {B2,-F2}>; //  W15
//  Order 6 : 4 + 6 = 10 classes.
//      Isomorphic to C_{6} : 4 classes.
S24 := sub<G | {A6}>; //  W1
S25 := sub<G | {-A6}>; //  W2
S26 := sub<G | {-A3}>; //  W3
S27 := sub<G | {-B3}>; //  W4
//      Isomorphic to S_{3} : 6 classes.
S28 := sub<G | {A3,D2}>; //  W5
S29 := sub<G | {A3,-D2}>; //  W6
S30 := sub<G | {A3,B2}>; //  W7
S31 := sub<G | {A3,-B2}>; //  W8
S32 := sub<G | {B3,G2}>; //  W9
S33 := sub<G | {B3,-G2}>; //  W10
//  Order 8 : 2 + 4 + 8 = 14 classes.
//      Isomorphic to C_{4} x C_{2} : 2 classes.
S34 := sub<G | {A4,-I}>; //  W1
S35 := sub<G | {B4,-I}>; //  W2
//      Isomorphic to C_{2} x C_{2} x C_{2} : 4 classes.
S36 := sub<G | {A2,C2,-I}>; //  W3
S37 := sub<G | {A2,D2,-I}>; //  W4
S38 := sub<G | {B2,E2,-I}>; //  W5
S39 := sub<G | {B2,F2,-I}>; //  W6
//      Isomorphic to D_{4} : 8 classes.
S40 := sub<G | {A4,B2}>; //  W7
S41 := sub<G | {A4,-B2}>; //  W8
S42 := sub<G | {-A4,B2}>; //  W9
S43 := sub<G | {-A4,-B2}>; //  W10
S44 := sub<G | {B4,D2}>; //  W11
S45 := sub<G | {B4,-D2}>; //  W12
S46 := sub<G | {-B4,D2}>; //  W13
S47 := sub<G | {-B4,-D2}>; //  W14
//  Order 12 : 1 + 7 + 3 = 11 classes.
//      Isomorphic to C_{6} x C_{2} : 1 class.
S48 := sub<G | {A6,-I}>; //  W1
//      Isomorphic to D_{6} : 7 classes.
S49 := sub<G | {A6,B2}>; //  W2
S50 := sub<G | {A6,-B2}>; //  W3
S51 := sub<G | {-A6,B2}>; //  W4
S52 := sub<G | {-A6,-B2}>; //  W5
S53 := sub<G | {-A3,D2}>; //  W6
S54 := sub<G | {-A3,B2}>; //  W7
S55 := sub<G | {-B3,G2}>; //  W8
//      Isomorphic to A_{4} : 3 classes.
S56 := sub<G | {B3,H2}>; //  W9
S57 := sub<G | {B3,I2}>; //  W10
S58 := sub<G | {B3,J2}>; //  W11
//  Order 16 : 2 classes.
S59 := sub<G | {A4,B2,-I}>; //  W1
S60 := sub<G | {B4,D2,-I}>; //  W2
//  Order 24 : 11 classes.
//      Isomorphic to A_{4} x C_{2} : 3 classes.
S61 := sub<G | {B3,H2,-I}>; //  W1
S62 := sub<G | {B3,I2,-I}>; //  W2
S63 := sub<G | {B3,J2,-I}>; //  W3
//      Isomorphic to D_{6} x C_{2} : 2 classes.
S64 := sub<G | {A6,B2,-I}>; //  W4
//  Subgroup S64b is in fact GL(3,Z)-conjugate to S64.
//S64b := sub<G | {A6,D2,-I}>; //  W5 : typo : (3,3) entry of gen 1 should be 1
//      Isomorphic to S_{4} : 6 classes.
S65 := sub<G | {C4,D2}>; //  W6
S66 := sub<G | {-C4,-D2}>; //  W7
S67 := sub<G | {D4,K2}>; //  W8
S68 := sub<G | {-D4,-K2}>; //  W9
S69 := sub<G | {E4,J2}>; //  W10
S70 := sub<G | {-E4,-J2}>; //  W11 : typo : (1,1) entry of gen 2 should be -1
//  Order 48 : 3 classes.
S71 := sub<G | {C4,D2,-I}>; //  W1
S72 := sub<G | {D4,K2,-I}>; //  W2
S73 := sub<G | {E4,J2,-I}>; //  W3

subgroupsGL3Z := [S01, S02, S03, S04, S05, S06, S07, S08, S09, S10, S11, S12, S13, S14, S15, S16, S17, S18, S19, S20, S21, S22, S23, S24, S25, S26, S27, S28, S29, S30, S31, S32, S33, S34, S35, S36, S37, S38, S39, S40, S41, S42, S43, S44, S45, S46, S47, S48, S49, S50, S51, S52, S53, S54, S55, S56, S57, S58, S59, S60, S61, S62, S63, S64, S65, S66, S67, S68, S69, S70, S71, S72, S73];

nSubs := #(subgroupsGL3Z);



//  Check pairwise Z-nonconjugacy. (Naive implementation.)

nConjugatePairs := 0;
for i in [1..nSubs] do
    for j in [(i + 1)..nSubs] do
        if (IsGLZConjugate(subgroupsGL3Z[i],subgroupsGL3Z[j])) then
            nConjugatePairs +:= 1;
        end if;
    end for;
end for;
printf "%o subgroups analyzed for Z-conjugacy. %o conjugate pairs found.\n",nSubs,nConjugatePairs;
print "";



//  Output set of maximal subgroups of each representative subgroup.

//  Function getIndex.
//  Input  : A finite subgroup of GL(3,Z).
//  Output : The index of a (in fact, the unique) Z-conjugate subgroup in the
//           list subgroupsGL3Z. If no Z-conjugate subgroup is found in this
//           list, then the function returns -1. (A return value of -1 should
//           never occur, if the input to the function is as specified above.)

function getIndex(H)
    for i in [1..nSubs] do
        if (IsGLZConjugate(H,subgroupsGL3Z[i])) then
            return i;
            break;
        end if;
    end for;
    return -1;
end function;



print "Subgroup ## : Indices of its maximal subgroups";
print "-----------   --------------------------------";
for i in [1..nSubs] do
    maxSubs := MaximalSubgroups(subgroupsGL3Z[i]);
    maxSubsIndices := {};
    for M in maxSubs do
        Include(~maxSubsIndices,getIndex(M`subgroup));
    end for;
    printf "Subgroup %2o : %o\n",i,maxSubsIndices;
end for;



exit;
```