# an element of $\text{SL}(3, \mathbf Z)$ of order 5

Tags: matrices

It is known that the orders of elements of $\text{SL}(2, \mathbf Z)$ are restricted: for example, there is no element of order 5.

What about for $\text{SL}(3,\mathbf Z)$? Does there exist an element of order 5? Of order 7? Of order any integer?

How would one go about constructing such a matrix?

Comment: There are some known results over finite fields, but I am not at all familiar with the $\mathbb{Z}$ case.

Comment: Note that Tahara has some typos and errors, as is worked out here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4219995

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element of order $n$ would have an eigenvalue of that order, necessarily together with the other $\phi(n)-1$ primitive roots of unity of that order, which means that $\phi(n)\leqslant3$, which gives the same crystallographic restriction as in dimension $2$: only orders $1,2,3,4,6$, as Mariano said in the comment.